# Quick Prolog Issue

Tags: prolog, predicate

If we have an unconditional statement like:

```
student(name, [class1, class2, class3, class4]).
```

What is the best way to retrieve *all students in class1*?

The method I am currently doing is..

```
class1_students(X):-
    student(X,[class1,__,__,__]).
```

But this only works for the above unconditional statement. And it will not work for unconditional statements such as:

```
student(name, [class2, class1, class3, class4]).
```

Because then I would need to adjust the conditional predicate to:

```
class1_students(X):-
    student(X,[__,class1,__,__]).
```

Do you see my dilemma? Is there a better way of doing this than having to hardcode it like I am doing? Because the unconditional statements can be in any form.

Comment: What's your definition of an *unconditional statement*? I am supposing you actually mean, *Prolog facts*. You need to use `member/2` to check what's in a list: `class1_students(X) :- student(X, Classes), member(class1, Classes).` or even more general, `class_students(Class, X) :- student(X, Classes), member(Class, Classes).` and query, `class_student(class1, X).`.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Another question if you don't mind.. If I have a prolog fact such as course(class,professor,unit).. And, I want to get find all courses with 2 or 3 units.. currently, i am doing "find_unit(X):- course(X,_,2)|course(X,_,3).". This gives me the right answer but not in the same order as the professor's. My answer gives all courses of unit 2 first and then all units of 3 after. However, the professor's order has the classes in the order that they appeared in the prolog facts.

Comment: `|` isn't a valid Prolog operator, and the double commas (`,,`) are a syntax issue as well. If you have another question, you should post it as a separate question and put in the actual code that you have tried, indicating what's wrong.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't format over properly. I meant that I am currently doing "find_unit(X):- course(X,_(underscore)_,2)|course(X,_(underscore)_,3)." which DOES work, but it's not in the correct order as it should be. With my current method, it is outputting all of the classes of unit 2 first, and then all of the classes of unit 3 after. Odd, because the '|' operator does do what I want it to do, kind of.. So it must be a valid Prolog operator? Additionally, I don't have a problem creating a new thread, but I don't want to spam since these two problems are pretty similar.

Comment: Which Prolog interpreter are you using? `|` isn't standard (unless you are using Definite Clause Grammars). The standard "or" operator would be a semicolon, `;`. The problems are different, even though they're for the same set of data. Your first question was about consolidating with proper list processing. Your new one is about order of goal satisfaction. Quite different. And on stackoverflow.com it's not standard practice to answer separate, new questions through the comments. Asking  a new question about a new concept isn't spam. Comment threads aren't supposed to be too lengthy. :)

Comment: @lurker I'm sorry, you're right. It is ';'. I am using Swipl on mac, btw. I am trying to create a new question, but it says I can only do so every 90 minutes. Do you mind if I just ask here temporarily? Say that I have the following Prolog facts: 'course(c1, ins, 2). course(c3, ins, 3). course(c2, ins, 2).' And, I need to write a query that finds all courses of unit 2 or 3. My approach is "findUnit(X):- course(X,(underscore),2);course(X,(underscore),3)." Which outputs c1, c2, and then c3. But, I need it to output it in the order they appear as fact as c1, c3, c2, and not in the order of units.

Comment: Here's a hint: think list membership, like in the first problem you described.

Comment: @lurker Yeah I figured I would try that approach, and thought that it should be **findUnit(X):- course(X,(underscore),U), member(3;4,U)." but that just gives me a false.. it makes sense logically, but what am I missing here? The only difference I see between this problem and the previous one is that the units 2 and 3 are not in a list, as opposed to how class1 was in a list.

Comment: Please read documentation for predicates before attempting to use them. There's plenty of it on SWI's website. That's not at all how `member` works and doesn't even match the way it's used in the last answer I gave.

Comment: @lurker According to documentation, member returns "True if Elem is a member of List. " In this case, when I try to do "findUnit(X):- course(X,(underscore),U), member(3,U)" doesn't work because the units are not in a list. Therefore, I don't think I should use member here at all, right? Is there any additional insight you can give me for this? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I assume this is an assignment, so I'm not going to hand out the answer. `member` will work very easily here. You just need to figure out how when you query, `member(X, L)`, what should `X` be, and what should the list `L` look like to achieve what you're looking for. Since `U` is not a list, trying to do `member(..., U)` with `U` as the second argument is obviously not the right approach.

Comment: @lurker I don't quite understand how I can possibly do that if the second argument of member has to be a list, especially considering that I can't just change the units in the Prolog facts to lists. course(X,(underscore),U), member(3,U) doesn't work because U is not a list.. I tried: findUnit(X): course(X,(underscore),U), member(3,[U]); course(X,(underscore),U), member(4,[U])." but same thing..

Comment: You have the concept backwards. You'd use `find_unit(X) :- course(X, _, U), memberchk(U, [3,4]).` or just `find_unit(X) :- course(X, _, U), (U = 3 ; U = 4).`

Comment: @lurker Yes, thank you I was able to figure that out earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You need a predicate which succeeds once if an element is inside a list, and fails otherwise. This predicate is [`memberchk/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=memberchk/2):

```
class_student(C, S) :-
    student(S, Cs),
    memberchk(C, Cs).
```